# Openui5: wrong sort order with sap.ui.model.Sorter

Tags: sapui5

It appears sap.ui.model.Sorter doesn't sort ISO-8859-1 characters correctly.

Below is an example where we create a list with one item pr character in the Norwegian alfabet. The output of this is not in the correct order, instead the order is "AÅÆBCDEFGHIJKLMNOØPQRSTUVWXYZ".

The expected results is the same order as when the alfabet variable is declared: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ"

How can we sort the model correctly?

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/xuyafu/

```
    var alfabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ"

var data = [];
for(var i=0; i< alfabet.length; i++){
  data.push ({value:alfabet.charAt(i)});
}

var modelList = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);

sap.ui.getCore().setModel(modelList);

var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("value", null, null);

       // Simple List in a Page
    new sap.m.App({
        pages: [
            new sap.m.Page({
                title: "Sorting with norwegian characters",
                content: [
                    new sap.m.List("list", {
                        items: {
                            path: '/',
                            template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                                title: '{value}'
                            }),
                            sorter: oSorter
                        }
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    }).placeAt("content");
```

[image: Output from code above]

Comment: Well, what would the correct order be? The one in the initial alfabet string? OpenUI5 uses JavaScript's built-in "localeCompare" string function: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/SorterProcessor.js#L48 (but without giving a locale). However, giving a locale does not seem to make a difference when doing "Æ".localeCompare("Z","no")...

Comment: @akudev yes, the correct order should be the one in the initial alfabet string. Let me check the localeCompare directly

Comment: If you think this might be a bug worth fixing post it at the github page of OpenUI5: http://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: @Niklas will do. This stackoverflow thread will be to implement a workaround

Comment: @akudev the locale for norway is nb.By using it, localeCompare returns the right value

'å'.localeCompare('z', 'nb');
1
'å'.localeCompare('z', 'en');
-1

Comment: @Niklas Issue 831 submitted https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input from the comments on the question, it is straight forward to override the sorting function fnCompare to get the right order

```
var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("value", null, null);

oSorter.fnCompare   = function (a, b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (b == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (typeof a == "string" && typeof b == "string") {
            return a.localeCompare(b, "nb");
        }
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here "nb" is the locale the sort is done with